# C# How can I solve limitations when using DirectoryInfo?

Tags: c#, .net, directoryinfo

When I recursive through some folders and files, I encounter this error:

The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directoryname must be less than 248 characters.

Here's my function

```
private void ProcessDirectory(DirectoryInfo di)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryInfo[] diArr = di.GetDirectories();

        foreach (DirectoryInfo directoryInfo in diArr)
        {
            if (StopCheck)
                    return;
            ProcessDirectory(directoryInfo);
        }
        ProcessFile(di);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        listBoxError.Items.Add(e.Message);
    }

    TextBoxCurrentFolder.Text = di.ToString();
}
```

I cannot make the directory names shorter, because I'm not allowed too so... How can I solve this problem?

**Added:**
Here's the other function:

```
private void ProcessFile(DirectoryInfo di)
{
    try
    {
        FileInfo[] fileInfo = di.GetFiles();

        if (fileInfo.LongLength != 0)
        {
            foreach (FileInfo info in fileInfo)
            {
                Size += info.Length;
                CountFile++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        listBoxError.Items.Add(e.Message);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Found this where he used Zeta Long Paths:
[How can I use FileInfo class, avoiding PathTooLongException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357358/how-can-i-use-fileinfo-class-avoiding-pathtoolongexception)

Have implemented it and now i'm going to let the program run over the night to see if it works.

**EDIT**
Used the ZetaLongPath yesterday and it worked great! It even went through folders that needed permission access.

**EDIT**
Instead of zetalongPath, I've used Delimon.Win32.IO.dll which i think is much better. It has the same interfaces as Win32.

Comment: I guess you have to go back to plain Windows API (FindFirst*/FindNext*)

Comment: So does the error occur from within `ProcessFile()`, maybe that code can be changed if we can see it?

Comment: You know that you are first to the deepest subfolder before you begin to process the files?! If you want to start with the rootfolder you should move `ProcessFile(di);` to the start of the method.

Comment: Musefan: No the problem doesn't occur there. Of course :) added the function

Comment: Tim: Yeah I know, got told that I should start from the deepest first.

Comment: +AirTrickz You should accept the answer of TripleAntigen.

Comment: As @TripleAntigen suggested in a comment bellow, AlphaFS github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS may have bugs but works fine for me to use Directory.GetFiles(,,SearchOption.AllDirectories) . Download and built in VS2017 which produce dlls for NetFx45/46/47/20, used in VS2019, nice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to resolve file path too long exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745215/best-way-to-resolve-file-path-too-long-exception)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's more info about the Delimon library referred to earlier. Its a .NET Framework 4 based library on Microsoft TechNet for overcoming the long filenames problem:

**[Delimon.Win32.I​O Library (V4.0)](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DelimonWin32IO-Library-V40-7ff6b16c#content)**.

It has its own versions of key methods from System.IO. For example, you would replace:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles
```

with

```
Delimon.Win32.IO.Directory.GetFiles
```

which will let you handle long files and folders.

From the website:

> Delimon.Win32.IO replaces basic file functions of System.IO and
>   supports File & Folder names up to up to 32,767 Characters.
>
> This Library is written on .NET Framework 4.0 and can be used either
>   on x86 & x64 systems.  The File & Folder limitations of the standard
>   System.IO namespace can work with files that have 260 characters in a
>   filename and 240 characters in a folder name (MAX_PATH is usually
>   configured as 260 characters). Typically you run into the
>   **System.IO.PathTooLongException** Error with the Standard .NET Library.

Comment: Heres another possible alternative called AlphaFS:  https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS

Comment: @ TripleAntigen great staff, open source. Delimon.Win32.IO seems to be close sourced from a company. AlphaFS may have bugs but works fine for me to use Directory.GetFiles(,,SearchOption.AllDirectories). Download and built in VS2017 which produce dlls for NetFx45/46/47/20, used in VS2019

Answer (score 2):

This is a known limitation in Windows:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx

I don't believe you'll be able to get around it, so whoever is telling you that you aren't allowed to make them shorter, you'll have a pretty solid argument as to why you have to.

The only real alternative is to move the deep folder somewhere else, maybe right at the root of your drive.

EDIT:  Actually there may be a workaround:  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/11/filesystem-paths-how-long-is-too-long.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use P/Invoke and the Unicode version of the Win32 API functions. You'll need `FindFirstFile`, `FindNextFile` and `FindClose` functions.

Also see:

- [C# deleting a folder that has long paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223007/c-sharp-deleting-a-folder-that-has-long-paths)
- [DirectoryInfo, FileInfo and very long path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394012/directoryinfo-fileinfo-and-very-long-path)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [subst](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cts=1331038651607&ved=0CD8QFjAB&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subst&ei=qwlWT6TDH9C2twfnvNzeCA&usg=AFQjCNHkp8jGh5_ejSbMj6g6s4KSrGFPIA&sig2=X1jwdLXmt-O7sPooIuTWnw) command. It creates a virtual drive starting at whatever folder you pass as parameter.

For example, you can turn the path c:\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\aaaaaaaaaaaaaa into the drive R: and continue exploring the subfolders of c:\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\aaaaaaaaaaaaaa thru R:...

Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score -1):

I also recommend reading this [three-part blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx) from the BCL Team, published in 2007, but relating specifically to the limitations of DirectoryInfo when it comes to deeply nested folders. It covers the history of the MAX_PATH limitation, the newer \?\ path format, and various .NET-based solutions and workarounds.

Comprehensive, though perhaps a bit dated.