# Get maximum directorydepth

Tags: c#, directory, subdirectory

I was just wondering, if there is a quick solution for getting the level of the deepest folder in my root Directory.

Lets say I work with "C:\" then I need a function which gets me the number of levels there are to the "deepest" folder in root directory without iterating over each directory.

Comment: How would you know the deepest level of any folder in your root drive if you don't want to iterate through it. (by yourself or any provided function in System.IO)?

Comment: The question is if there is a Function which gets it for me. I need to know the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [System.IO.DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383573(v=vs.110).aspx) `GetDirectories` recursively. Be sure NOT to use `SearchOption.AllDirectories` because that will
surely break with a security error!

```
static List<string> directories = new List<string>();
        static void GetDirectories(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
                {
                    var di = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
                    directories.Add(di.FullName);
                    GetDirectories(di.FullName);
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uaex) { }
            catch (PathTooLongException ptlex) { }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var path = @"C:\";

        GetDirectories(path);

        var maxLevel = directories.Max(d => d.Split('\\').Count());
        var deepest = directories.Select(d => new
            {
                Path = d,
                Levels = d.Split('\\').Count()
            })
        .OrderByDescending(d => d.Levels)
        .First();

    }
```

But you will run against a `PathTooLongException`, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584081/c-sharp-how-can-i-solve-limitations-when-using-directoryinfo) how to solve this.

Comment: But this will only get me all the SubDirs of C:\ or am I wrong ?

Comment: Hold on, I'll make you an example.

Comment: This is my longest (string) ;,,; C:\Users\OOO\.atom\packages\atom-yeoman\node_modules\tsd\node_modules\update-notifier\node_modules\latest-version\node_modules\package-json\node_modules\got\node_modules\duplexify\node_modules\end-of-stream\node_modules\once\node_modules\wrappy\test

Comment: KK nice imma try this out thanks alot for your effort

Comment: Nice job that Recursive call is doing a great job. still taking a while :P

Comment: Yeah, you should run this kind of things on another thread or buy a faster pc.. :)

Comment: Yeah its my pc at work ^^ my homemachine has an ssd ^^ was just wondering if its possible at all :D anyways thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I was bothered by the `PathTooLongException` and came up with this:

```
public static class DirectoryEx
{
    static char driveLetter;
    static string longPath;
    static List<string> directories;

    static DirectoryEx()
    {
        longPath = String.Empty;
    }

    private static char GetAvailableDrive()
    {
        var all = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray().Reverse();
        var occupied = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
            .OrderByDescending(d => d.Name)
            .Select(d => (char)d.Name.ToUpper().First());

        var free = all.Except(occupied).First();

        return free;
    }

    public static List<string> GetDirectories(string path)
    {
        directories = new List<string>();

        // recursive call
        FindDirectories(path);

        return directories;
    }

    static void FindDirectories(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
            {
                var di = new DirectoryInfo(directory);

                if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(longPath))
                    directories.Add(di.FullName.Replace(driveLetter + ":\\", longPath + "\\"));
                else
                    directories.Add(di.FullName);

                FindDirectories(di.FullName);
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uaex) { Debug.WriteLine(uaex.Message); }
        catch (PathTooLongException ptlex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ptlex.Message);

            longPath = path;

            Task t = new Task(new Action(() =>
            {
                CreateVirtualDrive(longPath);
                FindDirectories(driveLetter + ":\\");
                DeleteVirtualDrive();

                longPath = String.Empty;
            }));

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(longPath))
                t.RunSynchronously();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
        }
    }

    static void CreateVirtualDrive(string path)
    {
        driveLetter = GetAvailableDrive();

        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo() {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            Arguments = String.Format("/c subst {0}: {1}", driveLetter.ToString(), path)
        });

        while (!DriveInfo.GetDrives().Select(d => d.Name.ToUpper().First()).Contains(driveLetter))
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }

    static void DeleteVirtualDrive()
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            Arguments = String.Format("/c subst {0}: /D", driveLetter.ToString())
        });

        while (DriveInfo.GetDrives().Select(d => d.Name.ToUpper().First()).Contains(driveLetter))
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Use as `var directories = DirectoryEx.GetDirectories("C:\\");`

This will create a virtual drive (using `SUBST`) for each path that is too long so it can still iterate through it. Needs optimization and could be extended to provide some `DirectoryInfo` wrapper class.

Comment: Wow nice job :D didn't know such things are even possible :P

Comment: You're welcome, it's written in 1 go so you might want to see if you can improve it! ;)