# Path strings too long

Tags: c#, path

I have some path string which are too long to handle via FileInfo. So I am prepending the pathstring with @"\?\" because I read (for example in one the answers (unfortunately linkonly) in [How can I use FileInfo class, avoiding PathTooLongException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357358/how-can-i-use-fileinfo-class-avoiding-pathtoolongexception)  that this string would help with large pathnames (by forcing .NET to use Unicode mode which has a much higher limit than 260 or so)

But as soon as I use the whole string with the "long string"-identifier with the FileInfo class I get an error saying "Illegal char in path".

Am I missing something on how I can use this workaround?

Specific example:

```
fileInformations.FileLastChanged = File.GetLastWriteTime(_path); 
//this line causes the error.
```

Comment: Perhaps you can show the code that generates the error? That will help a lot.

Comment: See also [DirectoryInfo, FileInfo and very long path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394012/directoryinfo-fileinfo-and-very-long-path)

Comment: Isn't it \\?\ instead of \?\   ?

Comment: @Master117 in my case it is @"\?\"