# FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo() exception with very long paths

Tags: c#, .net

`FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo()` throws an exception when used with very long paths because it calls `Path.GetFullPath()`. How to solve this?

Example:

```
FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(veryLongPath)
```

Stack trace:

```
System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
   at System.IO.Path.SafeSetStackPointerValue(Char* buffer, Int32 index, Char value)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePathFast(String path, Boolean fullCheck)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetFullPathWithAssert(String fileName)
   at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(String fileName)
```

Comment: Can you show an example of this exception and the details obtained by the stack trace?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/

Comment: @Amy I'm using .NET framework 3.5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1357358/1498669